# Any good resources on Information Economics Theory?

Tags: game-theory, theory, political-economy, information, signaling

I am coming from a political economy/public choice perspective, trying to explore some ideas in signaling, especially the supply-side analysis of information transmission by the media/news. Although I know of some well-known papers written very close to my area of interest, the landscape of information economics, in general, has been hard for me to fully discover.

Is anyone familiar with a good book that can catch me up in this sub-field? Obviously, suggestions containing review papers, lecture series etc will also be excellent (if available). I am trying to learn about this topic from a theoretical perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the basics I always liked Varian's "Microeconomic Analysis" (the graduate book).

For a good introduction into game theory (with a nice chapter on signalling) I would first read Gibbons' "A primer in game theory" (in the US i think it's called Game Theory for Applied Economists.

Answer (score 1):

For other people who are interested, I had a talk with a professor who is a theorist and he pointed me to the following books:

Introductory coverage of main ideas:
"A Course In Microeconomic Theory" by David Kreps.
"Microeconomic Theory" by Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green.

More comprehensive work:
"The Theory of Incentives" by Laffont and Martimort.
"Contract Theory" by Bolton and Dewatripont.